# How do I close all open dialogs in a Swing application written with Java 1.4?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jdialog

Is there a way to programmatically close all open dialogs in a Java 1.4 Swing application?  I know that Java 6 has `Window.getWindows()` but that won't work for me.  We're stuck in Java 1.4.

Comment: Can't you just keep a list of Windows and when you want to close them, do a loop and close them one by one?

Comment: @JohannduToit I was just thinking that..

Answer (score 5):

See methods like:

- `Frame`

  - [`getFrames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames%28%29)
- `Window`

  - [`getOwnedWindows()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getOwnedWindows%28%29)
  - [`getOwner()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getOwner%28%29)

All were introduced with Java 1.2

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Frame.getFrames()` and then iterate recursively invoking `getOwnedWindows()` on all those frames and windows. However, I don't know if ownerless dialogs will be included in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can close a single frame using the code below:

```
for(Frame f: Frame.getFrames()) {
    if(f.getTitle().matches("Report Window")) { //your frame title
        f.dispose(); //or any other closing methods
    }
}
```

However, you can also dispose all of them if you remove the if-condition.